# How to generate vcvarsall.bat

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2015

My visual Studio 2015 installed without vcvarsall.bat.

[image: HDDContent]

This is not about how to find this file and I am also not a python developer.

MSDN states at the bottom of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx) page:

> The vcvarsall.bat file can vary from computer to computer. Do not
>   replace a missing or damaged vcvarsall.bat file by using a file from
>   another computer. Rerun Visual Studio Setup to replace the missing
>   file.

I am running the installation through our local IT department so I only get a fixed version of the setup. It looks like this setup does not install the batch file.

I wonder what other means of generating this "file" (actually it is several files and a folder structure) there are - how does the visual studio setup generate this file and is that generation possible without running the whole setup?

Comment: Have you installed visual C++/C++ sdk features?

Comment: No, this is not part the IT departments installation, I will note that. Would the batch script install itself if I grab a redistributable package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some option to "install" vcvarsall.bat.

- The obvious to rerun VS setup and add c++ features (maybe your IT dep is kind enough and...)
- Install [visual c++ build tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)
- Install [windows sdk](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) (select c++ related components)

Comment: Yeah, after identifying this a phone call to IT was enough. Good to know there are two additional options.